# FHSDK Error in xamarin app for RedHatMobileApps

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, xamarin.android, rhmap, feedhenry

so i try to connect or intergrate my apps in xamarin android to Redhat Mobile Apps bu i keep getting error message "An unhandled exception message ocured". here is the main activty

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Android.App;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Util;
using FHSDK;

namespace helloworld_xamarin
{
    [Activity(Label = "Quickstart HelloWorld", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
        private const string Tag = "MainActivity";

        protected override async void OnStart()
        {
            base.OnStart();
            await FHClient.Init();
        }

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

            var button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button);
            var result = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.result);
            var input = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.helloTo);
            button.Click += async delegate
            {
                result.Text = "Calling Cloud.....";
                var response = await FH.Cloud("hello", "GET", null, new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "hello", input.Text } });
                if (response.Error == null)
                {
                    Log.Debug(Tag, "cloudCall - success");
                    result.Text = (string)response.GetResponseAsDictionary()["msg"];
                }
                else
                {
                    Log.Debug(Tag, "cloudCall - fail");
                    Log.Error(Tag, response.Error.Message, response.Error);
                    result.Text = response.Error.Message;
                }
            };
        }
    }
}
```

is anyone have experience to intergrate xamarin mobile apps to redhat mobile apps service ? i already fill the fhconfig properties too with my app id, project id etc. i dont what my problem is because im new in red hat mobile apps

Answer (score 0):

Before you can fix the integration with RedHatMobileApps, you need to know what the actual Rxception is.

"An unhandled exception occurred" tells you nothing, except that your exception handling is inadequate. And that's because there's none in that `async` block.

So try adding some in:

```
button.Click += async delegate
{
    try {
        result.Text = "Calling Cloud.....";
        var response = await FH.Cloud("hello", "GET", null, new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "hello", input.Text } });
        if (response.Error == null)
        {
            Log.Debug(Tag, "cloudCall - success");
            result.Text = (string)response.GetResponseAsDictionary()["msg"];
        }
        else
        {
            Log.Debug(Tag, "cloudCall - fail");
            Log.Error(Tag, response.Error.Message, response.Error);
            result.Text = response.Error.Message;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Android.Util.Log.Error("buttonError", e.Message);
    }
};
```

If that doesn't catch it, have a look at `CurrentDomain_UnhandledException` and `AndroidEnvironment_UnhandledExceptionRaiser` which are last-ditch "catch *some* info about the exception" type handlers.

Once you've got a bit more information about the exception, it will be easier to track down.

[image: error message]

Comment: i add the break point on base.on start(), and the apps immediately show error message "An unhandled exception message ocured". maybe the error in fhsdk not my code ? do you have experience in redhatmobile apps ?

Comment: Could be - maybe comment out each line referring to fhsdk and see what happens next?

Comment: anyone have experience in redhat mobile app , help me please